# How to refresh a jQuery dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I am trying to refresh a jQuery dialog that contains information coming from my database.
When I change the context of the page, I click the button that opens my dialog, but it always shows me the first context. Does anyone know how to refresh the dialog?

Here is my code:

```
        function showDialog(id) {
            $('#' + id).dialog("open");
        }

        function closeDialog(id) {
            $('#' + id).dialog("close");
        }

        $('#DivDialogCibles').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            draggable: true,
            width: 1200,
            height: 600,
            cache: false,
            title: "Cibles annuelles",
            open: function () {
                jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function () {
                    jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
                })
            },
            close: function () {                 
                closeDialog('DivDialogCibles');
                $('#DivDialogCibles').html("");
            }
        });

        $('#btCiblesAnnuelles').bind('click', function () {
            showDialog('DivDialogCibles');
        });
```

and this is the code of my div :

```
    <div id="DivDialogCiblesAnnuelles" style="display: none"></div>
    <div id="DivDialogCibles" style="display: none">
    <%  using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditCible", "Enseigne", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "InitListGeneric", UpdateTargetId = "DivDialogCiblesAnnuelles" }, new { id = "formEditCibles" }))
    {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
        <table class="tableau">
            <thead >
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th colspan="2">Q1</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Q2</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Q3</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Q4</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:auto; resize:horizontal"><%: GetLocalResourceObject("LabelSecteur").ToString()%></th>
                    <% foreach (var periode in Model.PeriodesCible)
                    { %>
                        <th>I/H</th>
                        <th>% Prod</th>
                    <%} %>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <%:Html.Hidden("IdEnseigneDialog", Model.Enseigne.IdEnseigne) %>
                <%:Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.SegmentEnseigne.IdSegment, Model.ListeSegment, new { style = "display: none;"})%>
                <%:Html.Hidden("IDTFilialeProprietaire", Model.Enseigne.IDTFiliale)%>
                <% int cpt = 0; 
                var listESS = Model.Enseigne.ESS_Enseigne_Secteur.Where(tmp=>tmp.SEC_Secteur.IDTFiliale==Model.IdFiliale  && (tmp.SEC_Secteur.Suppression == false || tmp.SEC_Secteur.Suppression == null)).OrderBy(ob=>ob.SEC_Secteur.LibSecteur);
                var ListEssPeriodeCourante = listESS.Where(tmp => tmp.IdPeriodeCible == Model.Enseigne.RecupererPeriodeCourante()).OrderBy(ob => ob.SEC_Secteur.LibSecteur);
                foreach (var ess in ListEssPeriodeCourante)
                {%>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%:Html.DisplayFor(modelsec=> ess.SEC_Secteur.LibSecteur) %>
                        </td>
                        <% var ListEnseigneSecteur = listESS.Where(tmp => tmp.IdEnseigne == ess.IdEnseigne && tmp.IdSecteur == ess.IdSecteur).OrderBy(ob => ob.IdPeriodeCible); %>
                        <% foreach (var ensSec in ListEnseigneSecteur)
                        {%>
                            <%:Html.Hidden("ess.IdEnseigneSecteur_"+cpt.ToString()+"_"+ensSec.IdPeriodeCible.ToString(), ensSec.IdEnseigneSecteur) %>
                            <%:Html.Hidden("ess.IdSecteur_"+cpt.ToString()+"_"+ensSec.IdPeriodeCible.ToString(), ensSec.IdSecteur) %>
                            <%:Html.Hidden("ess.IdEnseigne_"+cpt.ToString()+"_"+ensSec.IdPeriodeCible.ToString(), ensSec.IdEnseigne) %>
                            <%:Html.Hidden("ess.PeriodeCible_"+cpt.ToString()+"_"+ensSec.IdPeriodeCible.ToString(), ensSec.IdPeriodeCible)%>
                            <td>
                                <%if (ensSec.IdPeriodeCible ==  Model.Enseigne.RecupererPeriodeCourante())
                                  {%>
                                    <%:Html.TextBox("ess.CibleItH_"+cpt.ToString()+"_"+ensSec.IdPeriodeCible.ToString(), ensSec.CibleItH, new { @disabled = "disabled" } ) %>
                                <%} %>
                                <% else
                                   { %>
                                    <%:Html.TextBox("ess.CibleItH_"+cpt.ToString()+"_"+ensSec.IdPeriodeCible.ToString(), ensSec.CibleItH) %>
                                <%} %>
                                <%:Html.ValidationMessage("CibleSecteurDialog", GetLocalResourceObject("LabelErrorCibleSecteur").ToString())%>                                          
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%if (ensSec.IdPeriodeCible ==  Model.Enseigne.RecupererPeriodeCourante())
                                  {%>
                                    <%:Html.TextBox("ess.CibleProd_"+cpt.ToString()+"_"+ensSec.IdPeriodeCible.ToString(), ensSec.CibleProd, new { @disabled = "disabled" }) %>
                                <%} %>
                                <% else
                                   { %>
                                    <%:Html.TextBox("ess.CibleProd_"+cpt.ToString()+"_"+ensSec.IdPeriodeCible.ToString(), ensSec.CibleProd) %>
                                <%} %>
                                <%:Html.ValidationMessage("CibleSecteurProdDialog", GetLocalResourceObject("LabelErrorCibleSecteurProd").ToString())%>                                          
                            </td>
                        <% } %>
                    </tr>
                    <% cpt++;
                } %>
                <tr>                           
                    <td style="border-top:1px solid #000"><label><%:GetLocalResourceObject("LabelCibleComplet").ToString()%></label></td>
                    <% foreach(var periode in Model.PeriodesCible) {
                        var cible = Model.EmptyCibleComplet;
                        if (Model.FilialeEnseigne.IdFilialeEnseigne != 0 && Model.FilialeEnseigne.CBC_CibleComplet.Count() != 0)
                        {
                            cible = Model.FilialeEnseigne.CBC_CibleComplet.SingleOrDefault(cb => cb.IdFilialeEnseigne == Model.FilialeEnseigne.IdFilialeEnseigne && cb.IdPeriodeCible == periode.IdPeriodeCible);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cible = Model.EmptyCibleComplet;
                        }
                        %>
                        <%:Html.Hidden("Cible.IdPeriodeCible_"+periode.IdPeriodeCible.ToString(), cible.IdPeriodeCible) %>
                        <%:Html.Hidden("Cible.IdFilialeEnseigne_"+periode.IdPeriodeCible.ToString(), cible.IdFilialeEnseigne) %>
                        <%:Html.Hidden("Cible.IdCible_"+periode.IdPeriodeCible.ToString(), cible.IdCible) %>
                        <td style="border-top:1px solid #000">
                            <% if (cible.IdPeriodeCible == Model.Enseigne.RecupererPeriodeCourante())
                            { %>
                                <%:Html.TextBox("Cible.CibleIthCmplet_"+periode.IdPeriodeCible.ToString(), cible.CibleItHComplet, new { @disabled = "disabled" })%>
                            <%} else { %>
                                <%:Html.TextBox("Cible.CibleIthCmplet_"+periode.IdPeriodeCible.ToString(), cible.CibleItHComplet)%>
                            <%} %>                                
                            <%:Html.ValidationMessage("CibleITHDialog", GetLocalResourceObject("LabelErrorCibleITH").ToString())%>                                          
                        </td>
                        <td style="border-top:1px solid #000">
                            <% if (cible.IdPeriodeCible == Model.Enseigne.RecupererPeriodeCourante())
                            { %>
                                <%:Html.TextBox("Cible.CibleProdComplet_"+periode.IdPeriodeCible.ToString(), cible.CibleProdComplet, new { @disabled = "disabled" })%>
                            <%} else { %>
                                <%:Html.TextBox("Cible.CibleProdComplet_"+periode.IdPeriodeCible.ToString(), cible.CibleProdComplet)%>
                            <%} %>   
                            <%:Html.ValidationMessage("CibleProdDialog", GetLocalResourceObject("LabelErrorProd").ToString())%>                                          
                        </td>
                    <%} %>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table> 
        <!-- Boutons -->
        <br />         

        <% if (Model.Enseigne.droitCreationModif == true) {%>
            <div class="divcenter">
                <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" id="btSaveCible" class='ui-button'/>
                <input type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" id="btCancel" class='ui-button'/>
            </div>
        <%} %>
    <% } %>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to include the code that populates your dialog in order for people to be able to help (as the answer below tries). Also, I believe `cache: false,` is not a valid option

Comment: thank you for your reply. I added the code of my dialog in my post

Comment: By the time the javascript is evaluated, all those async calls populating the DOM will have already been loaded, thus your script will only operate on HTML. You need to either store it somewhere to be appended dynamically or (better) simplify your server-side

Comment: what do you mean by simplifying server-side

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to re-load the contents of the dialog:

```
$('#DivDialogCibles').load('http://location.of.contents.of.div');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it shows me the error "Error Conection"

Comment: Just to check, you have updated the http://location.of.contents.of.div so that it's the address of the contents of the div on your server?

Comment: Yes i do this:                 $('#DivDialogCibles').load('~/Views/Enseigne/Edit.ascx');

Comment: Is this an MVC site? What do you get if you browse to that location in your browser? If it's MVC you'll need to make an action on your controller which serves Edit.ascx as a PartialView.

Comment: yes it is an VMC application and when I type the link into my browser it gives nothing
Ps: I already an ActionResult "Edit"

Comment: It looks like you need to use: $('#DivDialogCibles').load('http://server/controller/Edit'); If you've got any parameters they can be put in as the second parameter of the call: $('#DivDialogCibles').load('http://server/controller/Edit', {id:2});